# How to be notified when all prefetch links are ready?

Tags: javascript, preload, prefetch

I have a web page whose `head` contains some prefetch links:

```html
<link href="/fonts/my-font.ttf" rel="prefetch">
```

In a javascript script, I would like to be notified when these resources are ready.

I'm not sure at 100%, but the following code seems to work with preload links:

```js
// When this promise resolves, we are sure that all resources are loaded
return new Promise(resolve => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    resolve();
  } else {
    window.onload = resolve;
  }
});
```

I would like to do something similar, but with prefetch, as when this promise resolves, the prefetch queries are still running.

Comment: What is your goal with it? I am not sure, if there is an API available for it. Maybe there is another way to solve your issue.

Comment: Btw: Have you tried FetchEvent?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent

Answer (score 0):

According to [Resource Hints](https://w3c.github.io/resource-hints/), you can expect to see `load` and `error` events for issued speculative fetch requests (including link prefetch):

> 3.2 Load and error events
>
> The user agent MUST NOT delay the load event of
> the document due to outstanding preconnect or speculative fetch
> initiated requests.
>
> The decision on whether a resource hint is executed, and if so,
> whether full or partial processing is applied is deferred to the user
> agent. As a result, element-level load and error JavaScripts events
> are not guaranteed to fire, and if they do, do not guarantee that full
> processing was applied. However, the user agent SHOULD fire the
> appropriate load and error events when possible, to allow the
> application to track which hints were executed and when.

However note that the entire thing is up to the user agents, there are no guarantees about the prefetch of anything, and also remember that users may disable prefetching completely in various browsers.